# How to change substring from one column with value from another column vectorized - pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace, substring

I have a dataframe with one column being xml string (XML) and one of the columns (ICCID) holds values which needs to be used to replace substring in xml column per row. I would like to do this vectorized if possible so i tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)

columns = ['MSISDN', 'XML', 'ICCID', 'IMSI']
data = [['0123456789', '<subscriberInfo><msisdn>0123456789</msisdn><iccId>12345678998765432100</iccId><imsi>112233445566778</imsi><serviceProviderId>x</serviceProviderId><paymentType>POSTPAID</paymentType></subscriberInfo>', 89410123456789123456, 112233445566778],
['9876543210', '<subscriberInfo><msisdn>9876543210</msisdn><iccId>98765432112365478900</iccId><imsi>998877665544332</imsi><serviceProviderId>x</serviceProviderId><paymentType>POSTPAID</paymentType></subscriberInfo>', 89410987654321987456, 228024357302211],
['0123987456', '<subscriberInfo><msisdn>0123987456</msisdn><iccId>98765432198765432100</iccId><imsi>665544998877332</imsi><serviceProviderId>x</serviceProviderId><paymentType>POSTPAID</paymentType></subscriberInfo>', 89410987654321098765, 228024357302212]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
df['NEW_XML'] = df['XML'].replace(to_replace=[r'<iccId>\d{20}</iccId>'], value=[fr'<iccId>{df["ICCID"]}</iccId>'], regex=True)
```

This approach doesn't work since the targeted part/substring in xml string is replaced with actual pandas representation of Series as shown below:

`0    89410123456789123456\n1    89410987654321987456\n2    89410987654321098765\nName: ICCID, dtype: object`

The expected result for NEW_XML column would be like this:

```
NEW_XML
'<subscriberInfo><msisdn>0123456789</msisdn><iccId>89410123456789123456</iccId><imsi>112233445566778</imsi><serviceProviderId>x</serviceProviderId><paymentType>POSTPAID</paymentType></subscriberInfo>'
'<subscriberInfo><msisdn>9876543210</msisdn><iccId>89410987654321987456</iccId><imsi>998877665544332</imsi><serviceProviderId>x</serviceProviderId><paymentType>POSTPAID</paymentType></subscriberInfo>'
'<subscriberInfo><msisdn>0123987456</msisdn><iccId>89410987654321098765</iccId><imsi>665544998877332</imsi><serviceProviderId>x</serviceProviderId><paymentType>POSTPAID</paymentType></subscriberInfo>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
pat = r'(?P<before>.*<iccId>)(?P<iccid>\d{20})(?P<after></iccId>.*)'
xml = df['XML'].str.extract(pat).assign(iccid=df['ICCID'].astype(str))
df['NEW_XML'] = xml['before'] + xml['iccid'] + xml['after']
```

Output:

```
>>> df['NEW XML']
0    <subscriberInfo><msisdn>0123456789</msisdn><iccId>89410123456789123456</iccId><imsi>112233445566778</imsi><serviceProviderId>x</serviceProviderId><paymentType>POSTPAID</paymentType></subscriberInfo>
1    <subscriberInfo><msisdn>9876543210</msisdn><iccId>89410987654321987456</iccId><imsi>998877665544332</imsi><serviceProviderId>x</serviceProviderId><paymentType>POSTPAID</paymentType></subscriberInfo>
2    <subscriberInfo><msisdn>0123987456</msisdn><iccId>89410987654321098765</iccId><imsi>665544998877332</imsi><serviceProviderId>x</serviceProviderId><paymentType>POSTPAID</paymentType></subscriberInfo>
Name: NEW_XML, dtype: object
```

Details:

```
>>> xml
                                               before                 iccid                                                                                                                             after
0  <subscriberInfo><msisdn>0123456789</msisdn><iccId>  89410123456789123456  </iccId><imsi>112233445566778</imsi><serviceProviderId>x</serviceProviderId><paymentType>POSTPAID</paymentType></subscriberInfo>
1  <subscriberInfo><msisdn>9876543210</msisdn><iccId>  89410987654321987456  </iccId><imsi>998877665544332</imsi><serviceProviderId>x</serviceProviderId><paymentType>POSTPAID</paymentType></subscriberInfo>
2  <subscriberInfo><msisdn>0123987456</msisdn><iccId>  89410987654321098765  </iccId><imsi>665544998877332</imsi><serviceProviderId>x</serviceProviderId><paymentType>POSTPAID</paymentType></subscriberInfo>
```

Comment: You can edit the template to also override the “IMSI” value. The idea is to split your XML string into as many parts as necessary.

Comment: Hi @Corralien, thanks a million! That was what i have been looking for. I did it both for ICCID and IMSI column. My actual xml was like `<ns2:iccId>89410123456789123456</ns2:iccId>` so i adjusted a **pat** part. `pat = r'(?P<before>.*<ns2:iccId>)(?P<iccId>\d{20})(?P<after></ns2:iccId>.*)'`